# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar el valor mínimo de una matriz de map en c++?

Tags: c++, map

Estoy intentando encontrar el valor mínimo de una matriz usando la metodología "divide y vencerás".

Para ello he pensado en ordenar una matriz fila por fila, para luego encontrar sus valores mínimos, pero tengo un problema:

Mi matriz esta definida como `map<int, map<int, int> >` y, al intentar aplicar la función sort() de la STL, me da error.

Mi código es este:

```
for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
    sort(matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].end());
}
```

Quiero asignar esa fila a un vector para poder ejecutar la función pero no se como hacerlo.

También me interesaría en caso de no poderse hacer esa transformación encontrar otra forma de obtener ese mínimo.

¿Existe alguna forma eficiente de encontrar el valor mínimo de la matriz con esta metodología?

Comment: ¿ Por que no usas un `std::vector` directamente ? O incluso mejor, un arreglo `[100][100]` ? No veo la ventaja de utilizar un `map< int, map < > >`.  Usar un `int` como *key* para acceder a otro `map< >`. De hecho, será mas lento. No entiendo esa *retorcida* forma de usar un `map< >` para simular otras estructuras

Comment: Porque necesito introducir los datos de forma no contigua, y un `std::vector` no lo permite

Comment: ¿para qué quieres ordenar un `map`, si los `map`s ya contiene los elementos ordenados por su clave?

Comment: @Peregring-lk necesito obtener el valor minimo de cada fila, y no conozco otra forma de conseguirlo

¿Existe otra forma mas sencilla?

Comment: @AlmuHS No caigas en el error del problema XY (preguntar por tu solución Y (fállida); en vez de tu pregunta original, X: obtener el mínimo de cada fila). Rehaz tu pregunta para indicar exáctamente qué quieres conseguir y te pongo la solución si puedo. Respuesta corta: los mapas ya están ordenados según <, por tanto, el menor de la fila `i` será: `matriz[i].begin()->first`, si lo que quieres es la clave menor, o `matriz[i].begin()->second`, si lo que deseas es el valor de la clave menor. De todas formas, ¿cuál es tu problema real? Edita tu pregunta y déjalo lo más claro que puedas.

Comment: Ah, que está relacionado con http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/41408/como-obtener-el-minimo-valor-de-una-matriz-no-ordenada-usando-divide-y-venceras. Deberias empezar con indicar las estructuras de datos que usas y lo que has intentado.

Comment: Es la pregunta que hice antes, pero al no obtener respuesta la replantee aqui

Comment: Mejor borro la anterior y sigo en esta, si no teneis problema

Comment: @Peregring-lk tras hacer varias pruebas, he comprobado que las filas no siguen ningun orden, asi que estoy igual que al principio

¿alguna idea?

Comment: @AlmuHS Última pregunta, ¿cuál es el tamaño de la matriz? ¿Lo conoces en tiempo de compilación, en tiempo de ejecución pero antes de crear la matriz en sí, o es dinámica y puede crecer y decrecer? En el caso cotidiano donde el tamaño de la matriz es fijo, utilizar `map`s para representar la matriz es ineficiente, a no ser que sea una *sparse matriz*, dado que ordenar por índices, que son naturalmente ordenados utilizando vectores, tiene una sobrecarga extra innecesaria.

Comment: @AlmuHS ¿Y no contigua en qué sentido? Si la matriz es de nxn (por ejemplo), cuando busques el mínimo, ¿están ya los nxn elementos presentes en la estructura de datos, o la matriz podría ser incompleta o incluso con filas de diferente tamaño?

Comment: @AlmuHS La pregunta está fatalmente hecha. ¿Qué tiene que ver el divide y vencerás aquí? Esta pregunta causa más preguntas extra que posibles respuestas.

Comment: Pues es el tipo de algoritmo que debo usar para resolver este problema

Comment: @Peregring-lk en principio, la idea es que no se conozca el tamano de la matriz, por eso el usar map en lugar de vector.

Aunque, finalmente, lo he cambiado por vector y un tamano definido

Comment: @AlmuHS Los `std::vector`s también son dinámicos (comenzar con un vector vacío e ir añadiendo elementos con `.push_back(x)`). El problema es que un map es en realidad un árbol, y cada vez que utilizas el operador `[]`, se recorre dicho árbol interno para encontrar el elemento solicitado. Un `std::vector`, sin embargo, es una región de memoria continua, y utilizar `[]` para acceder a un elemento, no es más que una suma de punteros, es decir, una operación inmediata. El tamaño actual siempre puede conocerse con la función `.size()` o `.length()` de `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, cambie el std::map por un std::vector de tamaño definido, sacrificando flexibilidad y espacio por comodidad del algoritmo.

Para obtener el minimo, aplique std::sort() fila por fila, y luego recorri la primera columna comparando hasta obtener el menor.

Y, para saber a que posiciones (x,y) correspondia ese menor, genere una copia de la matrix original y recorri la fila correspondiente al minimo, hasta encontrar el valor dado.

De esta forma, la x es el numero de fila, y la y es el numero de columna

Answer (score 2):

Dado que los mapas ordenan por clave y no por valor, y tus claves son los índices de la matriz, no te queda otra que realizar una búsqueda lineal. Ordenar no puedes, porque los `map`s no se pueden reordenar, dado que rompes la relación de orden que el propio `map` intenta proteger, de ahí que te de error de compilación. Además, en caso de que pudieses (utilizando otra estructura de datos), ordenar solo para buscar el mínimo, es ineficiente también. El coste de ordenar es siempre mayor a buscar uno a uno. Tú necesitas ordenar cuando necesites los valores ordenados para más de una cosa. Así que:

```
#include <limits>

int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // Infinito
int i_min, j_min; // Coordenadas del mínimo

for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
    for (int j = start_dim2; j < end_dim2; ++j)
       if (matrix[i][j] < min) {
            min = matrix[i][j];
            i_min = i;
            j_min = j;
       }
```

Esto es más eficiente que utilizar `std::sort` o cualquier otro mecanismo que se te ocurra. Puede haber otras soluciones más eficientes pero todo depende de por qué estás representando matrices con `map`s o para qué querrías tener los elementos ordenados.

Answer (score 0):

Debes copiar todos los elementos de tu matriz a un arreglo unidimensional, de la siguiente forma:

```
vector<int> arregloTotal;
for(int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++){
 for(int k=0;k<matriz[0].length;k++){
      arregloTotal.push_back(matriz[i][j]);
 }
}
```

el `arregloTotal` tiene todos los elementos de tu matriz

Comment: y ¿no existe alguna forma mas eficiente?
Justo quería evitar eso

Comment: @AlmuHs no lo hay